# dont want to submit form when one of fields value is wrong or left empty

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, jdbc, struts

I am using Struts framework in my web application, i am facing problem in my coding when i click on radiobutton doctor hmm it asks for docid and so profile will be updated but if user doesnt give id and select doctor and save profile , menus of patient changes to doctor and user becomes doctor due to getter setter in beans have these values just update function doesnt works ..and same for pathologist..

```
<html:form action="upAction" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr class="show" id="admhide">
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap><bean:message key="sp.type"/></td>
            <td align="left" nowrap><html:radio property="type" value="Patient" name="reg" styleId="patradio" onclick="show(this.value);"/>Patient
                <html:radio property="type" value="Doctor" name="reg" styleId="docradio" onclick="show(this.value);"/>Doctor
                <html:radio property="type" value="Pathologist" name="reg" styleId="pathradio" onclick="show(this.value);"/>Pathologist</td>
        </tr>
<tr class="hide" id="doctor">
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap><bean:message key="sp.docid"/></td>
            <td nowrap align="left" ><html:text property="docid"  name="reg" styleId="docid"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide" id="patho">
            <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap><bean:message key="sp.pathoid"/></td>
            <td nowrap align="left" ><html:text property="pid" name="reg" styleId="pathid"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" nowrap><html:submit styleClass="button2" property="method"><bean:message key="userform.upd"/></html:submit></td>
            </tr>

  </table>
</html:form>
```

please help me how to do this so that if user fills wrong docid or no docid form dont sets rest values in getter setters and doesnt gets submit .. thankyou ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to apply JavaScript checks for Empty fields. 
go to this link for understanding Javascript Validations :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

For a wrong Doc Id, when the form is submitted you need to check the Doc Id first in your code before saving other details otherwise return the same page with errors like "wrong docid".

Comment: Doc Id which user is filling is in database . if user fills any .i want to match it with database stored value.there i am getting problem..

Comment: You need to compare the value that user is filling to the one in database using SQL query. You can also use Ajax to do the same by sending the filled in value and getting back response from the server about the validity of the Doc id.